# should I log transform my model for Linear Regression analysis

Tags: pandas, data-science, linear-regression

I have a dataset of boston houses with the following features

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 414 entries, 1 to 414
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column                                  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                                  --------------  -----  
 0   X2 house age                            414 non-null    float64
 1   X3 distance to the nearest MRT station  414 non-null    float64
 2   X4 number of convenience stores         414 non-null    int64  
 3   X5 latitude                             414 non-null    float64
 4   X6 longitude                            414 non-null    float64
 5   Y house price of unit area              414 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
```

standard deviation is:

```
X2 house age                                11.392485
X3 distance to the nearest MRT station    1262.109595
X4 number of convenience stores              2.945562
X5 latitude                                  0.012410
X6 longitude                                 0.015347
Y house price of unit area                  13.606488
dtype: float64
```

I tried to calculate the skew of prices and got the value of 0.599

I log transformed the data and got the value of -0.7064

the question that I'm having is, should I continue to work with dataset log transformed or it's not necessary to transform it, and when should I even consider log transform in my data analysis?

Comment: What are trying to achieve? Whether to log-transform or not it's a matter of opinion, depends on what your model suppose to do

Comment: @Roim I'm trying to create a simple linear regression model with 5 predictors to predict the value of prices (response)

Comment: Then do both, and see which model is doing better using cross-validation

Answer (score 1):

Using log transformation or not completely depends on what fits better on your data. Just calculate the performance of your models (log transformed and not) and see which one has the best performance metrics.